# How to upload image in firebase storage 5.0.1 with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

Recently a new version of firebase storage just came (5.0.1). There is a lot of changes. I can't seem to upload a photo and get the download URL of the photo. Can you provide a way to do it in firebase storage 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
```

for uploading file

```
Future<void> uploadFile(String filePath) async {
  File file = File(filePath);

  try {
    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref('uploads/file-to-upload.png')
    .putFile(file);
 } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
// e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
}
}
```

for getting download links:

```
Future<void> downloadURLExample() async {
 String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
  .ref('users/123/avatar.jpg')
  .getDownloadURL();

// Within your widgets:
// Image.network(downloadURL);
}
```

visit for depth details about this on https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage