# Can't get a proper URL when Image from Storage Firebase is linked to CloudFirestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I cant get a valid URL to retrieve in my method when images are linked to CloudFirestore from Storage in Firebase:

```
Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    Reference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('ifprofile/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {
      var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('/userProfile').add({
        "imageUrl": _imageFile.path,
       
      });
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('/influencerUser')
          .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
          .update({
// All fields you want to update in a document
        'imageUrl': IfUserProfile.imageUrl,
     
      });
      // Finish to Link images to Cloud Firestore
    });
    taskSnapshot.ref
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((value) => print("Image uploaded: $value"));
  }
```

into cloud firestore I get URL like this:

```
/data/user/0/it.test.testapp/cache/image_picker5217031945896769637.jpg
```

any input please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843474/how-to-upload-image-in-firebase-storage-5-0-1-with-flutter/64843892#64843892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to modify ur code a but like this

```
final url = await taskSnapshot.ref
    .getDownloadURL();
```

then take that url and put it in your firestore db

here is some code

```
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('$folderName/$imagename');
final uploadTaskSnapshot = await storageRef.put(image).future;

final imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: what do you mean as " then take that url and put it in your firestore db "

Comment: u need to await for that particular task to complete